# How can I implement a dependent select filter in a Symfony form for filtering Locations based on City selection?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, search, filter

I try to construct a Symfony form with dependent select which will be filter for instance Entity Locations. So, I have Zone → Country → Region → City entities, and I initialize a form where I have:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
  {
    $builder
        ->add('zone', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Zone::class,
            'placeholder' => '-- select a zone --',
        ])
        ->add('country', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Country::class,
            'placeholder' => '-- select a country --',
        ])
        ->add('region', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => Region::class,
            'placeholder' => '-- select a region --',
        ])
        ->add('city', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => City::class,
            'placeholder' => '-- select a city --',
        ])
    ;
    // Add listeners
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, array($this, 'onPreSetData'));
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, array($this, 'onPreSubmit'));

    // Filter Locations
  }
```

My goal is filtering Locations based on a chosen city (btw manytomany relation).

What's wrong with my FormType and what I have to do next?

Comment: Why do you think that something is wrong?

Comment: This code not working like a dependent select chiosetype fields